# Is it possible to see the JS related to the element in DevTools?

Tags: javascript, css

In the browser whenever I want to see a CSS added to the element I see it in the **Styles** section:

[image]

But what if I want to see a JS related to the element? Like, for example, a reference to the HTML element in a variable or that same variable related to functions, objects, and so on. Would it be possible in the same way as CSS?

I ask this because whenever I want to see some behavior in the element using JS I have to open the source code of the page in the browser and search line by line until I find the element code and that ends up being a lot of work.

Comment: As @meagar stated in their answer, the answer to this is a firm no. CSS is applied to elements, whereas JS intercepts/handles events that are triggered upon them. The "Event Listeners" tab is the closest you're going to be able to get and will allow you to see any event listeners that are attached to an element.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can look under `events` to see which of the elements events have handlers bound to them, but you can't see which variables hold references to a given element.